# How can we set new java parameters as default?

Tags: for-loop, parameters, jvm, addition, default

We are upgrading our system to java 17. However, we need to set some parameters after the transition. It is very difficult to add new parameters one by one to 200+ Tomcat jvms running on 10+ servers.

Also these tomcats run on vmware tcServer5. Any solution on Tcserver is suitable for us.

How can we do this in a short way?

We tried to add these two params but we couldn't come to a conclusion:

--add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal=ALL-UNNAMED

We will probably add new ones in the future.

Comment: You should rethink your way of writing software. Instead to “probably add new ones in the future” you should work on reducing the amount of deep reflection hacks, towards getting rid of those options.